Book in which a group of people go to a futuristic city where there are drugs with codenames like "Sugar" or "Brown Sugar"
I read it about 9 years ago, and I don't remember a whole lot. It might be a series of books instead of one singular book.
What I do remember is that at the beginning, there was a group of people (I can't remember how the book describes them; I imagined in my mind something similar to a tribe or village, but they weren't savages or anything like that. They were just a group of people away from the city) and I believe they got into some sort of altercation with city guard?
This is where the part gets fuzzy. I can't remember why or how they got to this futuristic city, but I do remember that there were drugs involved, and they had code-names (or maybe the "code names" were just the names that the author gave them), like "Sugar" or "Brown Sugar" (I remember telling my mom about it and she got mad that I was reading the book). I forgot exactly how the drugs were dispensed, but I believe middle-school me imagined something like an inhaler-type device. I think one of the ex-village people was really adapting to the new lifestyle, and was doing drugs, maybe joined the police?
There was a money system in there, but it was credits, and everything was digital. I believe you paid by using your arm or hand as well.
That's as much as I can remember; sorry if it isn't enough!

I'm not seeing anything that's actually science fictional here.

Brown sugar = Heroin; https://www.snohd.org/DocumentCenter/View/2516/Drug_Names_Slang_2019_05_09?bidId=

@Valorum Is money called "credits" anywhere except in science fiction?

@Valorum they had advanced drugs, a credits system with no physical currency, the city reminded me of the Cyberpunk punk game
